# Get Yelp Friends list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, yelp

So I've been tasked with designing a Web Application that utilizes a friends & followers list from Yelp.

Yelp has their own API, however, I can't find anything within the API that would allow me to query a search result that'll just have a user's friends and followers in Yelp listed. Is there something I am missing with the API, or is there a different way to perform this task?

Is it even possible to have a website integrated with the "Friend & Followers" database of an individual user?

The API Docs can be found at: http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/overview

Comment: There aren't "Friends & Followers" in Yelp API, just "Business" and "Search".

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, there is no Friends and Followers in the API. Yelp's main website has the ability to "add friends and Followers" so you can click a single friend and see what they've reviewed. I'm trying to tap into that info.

Comment: For example, you want this list of friends: http://www.yelp.com/user_details_friends?userid=inz8izVu0oSGeJJdY32zYA Is that?

Comment: Yep, I want that information. I and do you see how you can click on her reviews and it'll show you every single review she's ever made? I want to take her friends list, strip every review ever written by everyone of her friends, and let her search through that list for anything she wants and display the top results. So let's say 40 of her friends have eaten at Sushi places in Seattle, WA.  20 out of those 40 friends ate at the "Good Sushi" restaurant. 20 of her friends ate at "Bad Sushi Restaurant". When she searches for "Sushi" in "Seattle, WA" she'll only get Good sushi and Bad Sushi.

Comment: Using Html Agility Pack you get all you want. Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack

Comment: How would this even work? Are you trying to tell me to use HTMLAgilityPack to run through an entire page (like the one above) and have AgilityPack place every user into a variable, then place every business that every user reviewed on in a variable, then place every word of every review, of every business, of every user into a variable so that every user that uses this service can use up gods awful amounts of bandwidth (which goes against the Yelp ToS) on both Yelp and the service provider? If you think there is a way to do this, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just found my own answer through a rather round about process.

The Yelp API doesn't allow for any access to your friends because said data is attached through Facebook. Using the Facebook Graph API and Login API to allow for Yelp users to Login using their Facebook profile and then use the Graph API to pull all friends associated with that user account. Once that information is gathered you can use the Yelp API with reviews.user and match to the friends data gathered from the Graph API to pull the appropriate business and reviews.

Hope this helps someone else.